# taking data from specific rows

Tags: r, subset, rows

I'm attempting to use the following code to extract data from the two dates 01/02/2007 and 02/02/2007.

```
exdata1 <- exdata[c(01/02/2007,02/02/2007),]
```

But when I look at what code I've received, it gives me this.

```
> head(exdata1)
[1] Date                  Time                  Global_active_power   Global_reactive_power Voltage               Global_intensity      Sub_metering_1       
[8] Sub_metering_2        Sub_metering_3       
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Can someone tell me what's going wrong? I'm completely lost.

Comment: Please `dput(exdata)` to share your data

Comment: It's the electric power consumption txt file       
https://github.com/rdpeng/ExData_Plotting1
exdata is me reading the data like this
read.table("household_power_consumption.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";")

Comment: First, work with actual dates and coerce `exdata$Date <- as.Date(exdata$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")`. Then subset `d <- as.Date(c("01/02/2007", "02/02/2007"), "%d/%m/%Y");exdata[exdata$Date %in% d, ]`.

Comment: Or `subset(exdata, Date %in% d)`.

Comment: Hey thank you so much with this, head() shows useful info now.
Is there a reason why the dates must be coerced?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get no data is simple: the dates you are looking for are specified differently in the data itself: not `01/02/2007` and `02/02/2007` but `1/2/2007` and `2/2/2007`. Also, the `Date`column is a factor column (cf. `str(data)`). To access factors, you can use quotes around the dates:

```
example <- data[data$Date=="1/2/2007"|data$Date=="2/2/2007",]
head(example)
          Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity Sub_metering_1
66637 1/2/2007 00:00:00               0.326                 0.128 243.150            1.400          0.000
66638 1/2/2007 00:01:00               0.326                 0.130 243.320            1.400          0.000
66639 1/2/2007 00:02:00               0.324                 0.132 243.510            1.400          0.000
66640 1/2/2007 00:03:00               0.324                 0.134 243.900            1.400          0.000
66641 1/2/2007 00:04:00               0.322                 0.130 243.160            1.400          0.000
66642 1/2/2007 00:05:00               0.320                 0.126 242.290            1.400          0.000
      Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3
66637          0.000              0
66638          0.000              0
66639          0.000              0
66640          0.000              0
66641          0.000              0
66642          0.000              0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your efforts show several misconceptions about how the R language works. To see what R "thought" the vector in the `i` position for the "[" function was, just type the vector code to your console:

```
c(01/02/2007,02/02/2007)
[1] 0.0002491281 0.0004982561
```

So you were actually submitting a numeric vector that contained decimal fractions close to zero. You can use numeric vectors for selection, but they need to be integers more than 1. Even if you did understand that R wasn't going to use those as dates and tried to format as an R "Date"-classed value, you still wouldn't have succeeded by just using those dates as an index since R Dates are actually integers representing the number of days since Jan 1, 1970 and those dates would have been taken a very large values (13545 and 13546):

```
dput( as.Date(c("01/02/2007","02/02/2007"), format="%d/%m/%Y") )
# structure(c(13545, 13546), class = "Date")

mydf = data.frame( d=as.Date( c("01/02/2007","02/02/2007"), format="%d/%m/%Y") , letters[1:2] )
mydf
#------------
           d letters.1.2.
1 2007-02-01            a
2 2007-02-02            b

mydf[ as.Date( c("01/02/2007","02/02/2007"), format="%d/%m/%Y") , ]
#----------------
        d letters.1.2.
NA   <NA>         <NA>
NA.1 <NA>         <NA>
```

So the answer to your last comment/question: those expression you were calling "dates" were never dates in the first place; they were just numbers separated by slashes and those together were evaluated by R as arithmetic expressions, i.e. as numbers separated by the division operator. Even though converting to "Date"-class would give you a set of integers, but they would not be handled by the R interpreter in the manner you expected. You needed a mechanism for *matching* Dates to Dates. The `%in%` infix operator is really a dressed-up version of the R function `match`. The `%in%` function was actually building a logical vector that could be used for selecting the matching rows:

```
 mydf$d %in% as.Date( c("01/02/2007","02/02/2007"), format="%d/%m/%Y") 
[1] TRUE TRUE

 mydf[ mydf$d %in% as.Date( c("01/02/2007","02/02/2007"), format="%d/%m/%Y") , ]
           d lets
1 2007-02-01    a
2 2007-02-02    b
```

Comment: thanks for this, I'm trying to learn r as fast as possible, but it seems the basics will still take a while to be digested

Comment: My advice is to start by learning the basic atomic classes: "character", "numeric", "logical" and the classes with attributes: "factor", "Date", and POSIXct" and the more flexible classes: "list", and "data.frame". Try to read the help page for any function that throws an error and try to understand how each function has a limited number of classes that it will accept for its various parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine, you just didn't specify what columns you were filtering for :
exdata[c(01/02/2007,02/02/2007),] vs
exdata[date Column %in% c(01/02/2007,02/02/2007),]

Comment: This is completely, entirely incorrect. Please learn the difference between numeric and character classed expressions in R.